# How to test-sign minifilter in Jenkins CI build?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, jenkins, msbuild, wdk

I use Jenkins for continuous integration and have it building my minifilter on Windows 2012 R2. I have `jenkinsslave-c__jenkins` running as a service on the build box, which runs as `Local System`. Unfortunately, this setup does not allow for signing the minifilter:

I build with this:

```
msbuild myMiniFilter.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

but then I get this error:

```
...
TestSign:
  The driver will be test-signed. Driver signing options can be changed from the project properties.
  Sign Inputs: c:\jenkins\workspace\myMiniFilter-build-official-master\x64\Release\myMiniFilter.sys
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe sign /ph /sha1 "01245E502A4362B3826701F31112361631E67033" 
  Done Adding Additional Store

  Number of errors: 1

SIGNTASK : SignTool error : The signer's certificate is not valid for signing. [c:\jenkins\workspace\myMiniFilter-build-official-master\myMiniFilter\myMiniFilter.vcxproj]
SIGNTASK : SignTool error : An error occurred while attempting to sign: c:\jenkins\workspace\myMiniFilter-build-official-master\x64\Release\myMiniFilter.sys [c:\jenkins\workspace\myMiniFilter-build-official-master\myMiniFilter\myMiniFilter.vcxproj]
...
```

When I RDP into the box and build as administrator, I do not have any problems signing with the WDKTestCert associated with that account.

I have looked at other questions and solutions, but I would prefer to not create a Jenkins user. I'm running on an AWS instance, and having it just run as a service facilitates easier maintenance. Is there a way I can import/create a cert that will then allow for signing?